# Filter dataframe by time period and id in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate, posixct

**Problem:**

I am trying to filter my dataframe by specific datetimes that are dependent on an ID vector.

Specifically, for observations where `df$id == "A"`, I want to remove rows between `2017-08-05 00:20:00` and `2017-08-10 13:55:00`. However, for observations where `df$id == "B"`, I want to remove rows between a different time interval, `2017-08-05 00:30:00` and `2017-08-10 13:55:00`.

**Example dataframe:**

```
date <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-04 16:40:00","2017-08-05 00:20:00","2017-08-10 13:55:00","2017-08-15 08:35:00", "2017-08-04 17:20:00","2017-08-05 00:30:00","2017-08-10 13:55:00","2017-08-15 09:30:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
value <- as.numeric(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))
id <- as.factor(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"))
df <- data.frame(date, value, id)
```

**Desired output:**

```
               date value id
2017-08-04 16:40:00     1  A
2017-08-15 08:35:00     4  A
2017-08-04 17:20:00     1  B
2017-08-15 09:30:00     4  B
```

**Thanks!**

**Edit:** if your dataframe has a third category (`df$id == "C"`) that you want to preserve in its entirety:

```
df[which(
  (df$id == "A" & (df$date < "2017-08-05 00:20:00" | df$date > "2017-08-10 13:55:00")) |
    (df$id == "B" & (df$date < "2017-08-05 00:30:00" | df$date > "2017-08-10 13:55:00"))
 | df$id == "C"), ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[which(
        (df$id == "A" & (df$date < "2017-08-05 00:20:00" | df$date > "2017-08-10 13:55:00")) |
        (df$id == "B" & (df$date < "2017-08-05 00:30:00" | df$date > "2017-08-10 13:55:00"))
      ), ]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close, but the first date within the `df$id == "B"` should be `2017-08-05 00:30:00` instead of `2017-08-04 17:20:00`.

Comment: This solution worked for my example, but doesn't do exactly what I would want for my actual data. What would you do if you wanted to apply the same date filters for `A` and `B`, but you wanted to keep all of the data for a different id, say `df$id == "C"`?